# B spline processing power

Tags: graphics, interpolation

I am new to curve interpolation methods, but not sure if it could solve my problem. I have 128 video samples every 1ms and want to smoothen them using (probably) B spline. Knowing that I have to use some microcontroller (probably some M4 Cortex), I wonder what processing power (eg. de Boor) algorithm requires ? It should be nice to fit all the calculations in 1ms time limit. I also don't know if the output of algorithms is new series of samples or some polynomial function or series of splines or ... ?

Comment: have you sample input? what are the video samples? is it a frame/iamge? or what? what do you mean by smooth. You want to smooth geometry or intensity ... between neighboring pixels or consequent frames ? Power depends on the task and data ... i sit integer or float? how many bits etc ... for smoothing there are other options like FIR or convolution (which is also a FIR)

Comment: Samples are from one-line 128 pixel sensor. They are noisy and I have to find some change in (black -white) intensity. So I thought to interpolate intensity of that (one line) samples to acquire smooth (first and second derivative) function and then do some mathematics. You are right regarding power - samples are 10 bits. AFAIK B Spline doesn't include sampled points, but passes "in between", which better suits.

Comment: hmm I would do FIR like averaging or sliding average on few consequent lines (only between corresponding pixels) that should dumpen the noise a lot at very low processing cost and can be done on integers too if your HW does not have FPU. No need for SPLINES

Comment: I have some thoughts not to rely on single (128 pixel) samples but to compare eg. two successive series, although not in sense you proposed. It seems better and easier then interpolation approach. However for sake of future tasks, it is interesting to learn how demanding is interpolation. Thanks @Spektre for valuable and different point of view.

Comment: on integers its easy just few additions and multiplications ... on HW without multiplyer it can be encoded as LUT so I see no big speed issue here even for SPLINES ... however if using floats that is another story  especially on MCU/DSP without FPU